# How to handle mountain lion notifications clicks

Tags: objective-c, macos, notifications, osx-mountain-lion

I just wanted to add some notifications to Gyazo app.
I finally able to send notifications to the notifications center http://korniltsev.ru/p/jz6m3Nm.png
however when i click on it and the app is not launched it launches in some strange way:
it shows empty window(even if i set it visibleAtLaunch to 0) and nothing happens;http://korniltsev.ru/p/jz6mvk0.png

the code i'm trying to use is here:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSUserNotification * clicked = [[aNotification userInfo]
            objectForKey:NSApplicationLaunchUserNotificationKey];
    if (clicked){
        [NSApp terminate:self];
        return;
    }
...
```

I send notifications like this

```
NSUserNotificationCenter *manager = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];
NSUserNotification *urlNotification = [[NSUserNotification alloc]init];
[urlNotification setTitle:appName];
[urlNotification setInformativeText:url];
[manager deliverNotification:urlNotification];
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`[NSApp terminate:self]` has a lot of side effects. Are you sure these side effects are not creating your blank window? Have you tried calling `[NSApp terminate:self]` immediately in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and making sure you application quits cleanly in every case? If it does not you will likely have to look at what you are doing in your application's document controller (if you have one) and `applicationShouldTerminate`.

Comment: If i call `[NSApp terminate:self]` right in applicationDidFinishLaunching the app is termianted properly. If i change terminate call on `exit(0)` the result is the same. I don't have adocument controller.